# How to Jump to the next tag while working with Eclipse or Aptana Studio?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I'm using Eclipse IDE and Aptana Studio. Is there any keyboard-shortcut that takes indicator to the next tag?  I think the keyboard-shortcut is the same in both IDEs.

Comment: You mean XML/HTML files, right? I don't mean about the extension, but the content.

Comment: yea I'm working on an HTML file. I've got a lot of `<li>` tags to work with. so I need to jump down to next one to fill in the content. but it's so hard without a short cut key cause I have to go down every time and get back. so that would be great if there is a keyboard short cut.

Comment: So I guess my answer fits on your case... try it out :)

Comment: I pressed Ctrl+Shift+L and tried a lot of keyboard shortcuts there. many of them does not work. Is there anything I should do before pressing those keys? 
Ctrl + shift + up/down does not work on '<li>' tags for me :(

Comment: It works, you may be doing something wrong. Where are you putting the cursor before you try the shortcuts?

Comment: I put cursor before the tag, in the middle of the tag, on the tag and even after the tag. none of them works. here is a screen shot. 
[img16.imageshack.us/img16/1047/38533682.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1047/38533682.png)

Comment: Well, it may be related to the PHP Code Editor... try opening this file in the general-purposes HTML Editor to see if it works there.

Comment: Hey man I finally found the short key. it's just the tab button! but there is one thing you should do before and that is going to help>install new software and add this address http://update.aptana.com/update/studio/3.2 
after then you need to find HTML editor (use filters) and there you go. now you can use tab key to move to next tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Ctrl + Shift + Arrow Up/Down`

It works only inside a parent Tag. For example, if you have a Parent Tag called `<Books>` and lots of child Tags called `<Book>`, if you place the cursor over a `<Book>` Tag, you can navigate (via the mentioned shortcut) between every book. When you reach the last one, it doesn't go off the `</Books>` Tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Page up/ page down I guess and 
Ctrl + Shift + L : will show all shortcuts.

Comment: I pressed Ctrl+Shift+L and tried a lot of keyboard shortcuts there. many of them does not work. Is there anything I should do before pressing those keys?

Comment: @Iman: Can you give any example ? I haven't tried all but believe that they all work.

Comment: yea dude. next sibling and previous sibling does not work. Ctrl + shift + down/up

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the short key. it's just the tab button! but there is one thing you should do before and that is going to help>install new software and add this address http://update.aptana.com/update/studio/3.2 
after then you need to find HTML editor (use filters) and there you go. now you can use tab key to move to next tag.

Answer (score 0):

With Aptana 3 you can use `ctrl + numpad 8` to go up or `ctrl + numpad 2` to go down a list of markup elements. Did the work for me :)

EDIT : Well it worked only because I had Zen Coding installed, so if you want that functionality you can install zen coding (which is a must have anyway).

You may have to change the key binding.